# How to run two SQL queries together?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two sql queries I want to run at once so I don't have to run twice to get the result

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM attendance WHERE month =10 and grade =  4

SELECT COUNT(*) from attendance WHERE month = 10 and grade  = 4 AND userid = 24 and attendance = 'present'
```

I want two counts of total class and total number of classes in which student is present.

Comment: Since you've already got an answer that should suffiecently solve your question, you should in my opinion also think about your table's structure. It's strange having a column name which is identic to the table name, also it's mostly no good idea to split parts of a date into different columns. It's usually better to have the whole date in one single column and use functions if it's required to split it within a query.

Answer (score 5):

You can combine the second criteria using *conditional aggregation*, this way the table is only read once.

```
select 
  Count(*) as TotalCount, 
  Count(case when userid = 24 and attendance = 'present' then 1 end) as StudentCount
from attendance 
where month = 10 and grade = 4;
```